# POSIX to Olson/IANA timezone format conversion

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I work with old devices which send some metadata to server. I need to manipulate date time which is in UTC. I also get timezone information where devices are located in POSIX format eg. for Berlin:

`CET-1CEST,M3.5.0/2,M10.5.0/3`

However, this format doesn't seem to be supported by popular libraries like `pytz`

Thus I thought I would simply convert this to Olson format which would be: `Europe/Berlin`

But I can't find way to convert POSIX format to Olson format (which I thought was common thing and well supported). How would you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot convert from POSIX to Olson.

POSIX strings are a format for encoding offsets, abbreviations, and transitions.  They can only represent a single "standard time" offset, an optional single "daylight time" offset, and a single pair of transitions between them.

Olson strings (aka IANA, tzdb, tzinfo, etc.) are *identifiers*.  They reference a `Zone` or `Link` entry in the tz data.  Each zone can contain any number of offsets and transitions (using `Rule` entries).  This allows for true representation of how time zones change over time.

One can project a POSIX string for a given Olson time zone and a given point in time (such as "now"), but the reverse is not possible.

In the example you gave, given `Europe/Berlin`, I could compute the current POSIX string, which would look like what you showed.  But the exact same string would be computed for `Europe/Paris` and several other distinct time zones that have their own set of changes over time.  There's no way to distinguish between them.

Comment: Also, if POSIX time zone strings are a hard requirement, then 1) understand their limitations, and 2) look for a library or platform support specifically for them.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed replay. We use Python exclusively and doesn't look like there is any support for POSIX format. I think I will either try to get TZ in different ways or just write small script to manipulate this format as my usecase is quite simple.

Comment: Perhaps try [this one](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PosixTimeZone)?  The example shows Olson IDs, but if it's just passthrough to OS, then it should work (in theory) with POSIX strings as well.