# none IANA time zone - usage still possible?

Tags: go, timezone, posix, iana

I need to use time zone strings like this:
`CET-1CEST,M3.5.0,M10.5.0/3`
`CET-1CEST-2,M3.5.0/02:00:00,M10.5.0/03:00:00`

But the go time pkg is using the IANA Time Zone database e.g.: `Europe/Paris`

Is there perhaps a way to use or convert the strings?
I want to add/subtract time differences of various zones.

Comment: related (although Python-tagged): [POSIX to Olson/IANA timezone format conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43050855/10197418)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to build (or find) a map of 3-letter time zones to IANA time zone that covers the time zones you'll be seeing.

The reason being that 3-letter time zones like `CET` are not guaranteed to be unique (and are, in fact, not unique).

For instance, `CET` covers multiple TZDB time zones. They are all UTC+0100, but vary in

- whether or not they observer Daylight Savings/Summer Time, and
- The dates of the switch from standard time to daylight savings/summer time and vice-versa.

And `PST` covers "Pacfic Standard Time" (UTC-0800/UTC-0700), covering the west coast of the USA, but it also covers Asia/Manila (UTC+0800/UTC+0800).

There are lots more anomalies like that: the world is a big place, with lots of different governments and cultures.

Also, history matters: the geographic boundaries of time zones have changed over the years, as have the rules surrounding daylight savings times. So to get an accurate notion of a local time measurement relative to UTC, in addition to the local time measurement itself, you need to know not only where the measurement was taken, but when it was taken.

[and it gets worse if you have to consider the shift from the Julian to the Gregorian calendar: that took centuries to complete. Russia, for instance, didn't switch to the Gregorian calendar until after the Bolshevik Revolution at the end of the 1st world war.

Comment: Respectfully, this does not answer the question that was asked.  The OP has a [POSIX time zone string](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/TZ-Variable.html) (not just a 3-letter identifier) and wants to use it with Go.   I agree, an IANA identifier would be more useful, but it's not what was asked here.